# Angularjs ng-class not working as expected

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a angularjs app and I am trying to use the angularjs ng-class operator to toggle between two classes. I have tried using the ternary operator and have moved back to do it the old way.  Below is my code:

```
<span ng-class="{'expand':boolExpander,'undoExpand':!boolExpander, }" ng-init="boolExpander=false" ng-click="boolExpander=!boolExpander"></span>
```

The span tag is just a holder for an icon which is defined in the css as such:

```
.expand {
    background: url(../assets/icons/glyphicons/glyphicons/png/glyphicons_432_plus.png) no-repeat 6px center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}
```

As you can imagine the `undoExpand` class selects a different icon, but is otherwise exactly the same.

Whenever the user clicks the first time, the angularjs app throws an Error, "undefined is not a function"  and then after clicking a few more times, the entire span goes away.

So what is happening and why?  It seems like this should be straightforward and just work.

Here is the entire Error that happens when the ng-Click is triggered:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.h [as fn] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:140:281)
    at k.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:109:403)
    at k.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:112:398)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:194:147)
    at HTMLSpanElement.m.event.dispatch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:3:8436)
    at HTMLSpanElement.r.handle (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:3:5146) angular.js:10061(anonymous function) angular.js:10061(anonymous function) angular.js:7357k.$digest angular.js:12531k.$apply angular.js:12777(anonymous function) angular.js:19093m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<span ng-class="{'expand':boolExpander,'undoExpand':!boolExpander }" ng-init="boolExpander=false" ng-click="boolExpander=!boolExpander"></span>
```

The comma at the end of the `ng-class` was generating an error.

### [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9887x5ut/)

Comment: Once I click the span it generates an error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`  It only happens on the first click. After 4 clicks the entire span is removed.

Comment: Maybe something else is causing this error, I'm just not sure how to find what is happening. I know that both examples provided so far should work. ugh.

Comment: @schumacherj I'm sorry, but with the amount of information that we have it's impossible to know what it's causing that error, but I'm positive that it can't be the ng-click="boolExpander=!boolExpander", because if it was then the example that I've shared in my answer would trigger that error too. Could you please share the rest of the code? or even better: could you please create a jsFiddle or a plunker reproducing this issue, so that we can help you to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<span ng-class="(boolExpander) ? 'expand' : 'undoExpand'" ng-init="boolExpander='false'" ng-click="boolExpander=!boolExpander"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
ng-class="{true:'expand',false:'undoExpand'}[boolExpander]"
```